# How can i make a quicklist for empathy to start a conversation with a certain "friend"?

Tags: empathy, quicklists

I would like to create a quicklist for empathy including links to certain msn and facebook "friends" of mine. I already know how to make quicklists, I just need the command i have to use in order to start a chat window with a certain user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empathy itself does not seem to have any options to supply it with a username. I do not believe this is possible at the moment (and have not seen any reference while searching for any sort of plugin that can do this).

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ empathy --help
Usage:
  empathy [OPTION...] - Empathy IM Client

Help Options:
  -?, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -n, --no-connect         Don't connect on startup
  -h, --start-hidden       Don't display the contact list or any 
                           other dialogs on startup
  -v, --version            
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

I would start with filing a feature request for this on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/empathy).

Comment: Do you know whether this is possible in any other messaging application?

Comment: @Chriskin: Gaim and Pidgin don't either. I have not seen an IM capable of this.

Comment: Thanks . I'll leave it as unanswered for a day or two in case someone knows of an app that can do it and fill a feature request in the meantime. If nobody comes with an idea, i'll tick your message as the answer.